# How to send notification to specific people even if the app is closed?

Tags: android, service

I want to make an app that if someone click on the button everyone in the 100 meters radius from this people get notification even if the app is closed, and of course those people have the app. How can I make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by combining Location Listeners and Google Cloud Messaging for Android

you can read more about GCM [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: I found an android function "add proximity alerts" that send notification  to all the people who are in the radius (for example 100 meter) of my latitude and longitude for example. Were I need to put this function (In what part of my app I need to put it, for example in the service file)?